# Swift 3.0 Textfield in a TableViewCell not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, textfield, custom-cell

I am trying to display a textfield on a tableview using a custom cell. I think I have set up the delegation protocol properly, but when loaded, the tableview doesn't show the textfield. I have added a textfield into the customcell, set the class to CustomCell, and changed the identifier to "Cell", but I am not sure what else I am missing.

view controller with tableview:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! 


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Hello")

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.cellDelegate = self
    cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: cell.textField)
    cell.textField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    cell.textField.text = "Test"

    return cell
}

func didPressTextField(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("textfield was tapped")
}
```

custom cell VC:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate : class {
    func didPressTextField(indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var cellDelegate: CustomCellDelegate?
    var indexPath: IndexPath!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.cellDelegate = nil
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func textFieldWasTapped(_ sender: UITextField) {
        self.cellDelegate?.didPressTextField(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
```

Comment: Have you set the delegate to self.

Comment: Does the other methods of tableview are being called?

Comment: @Saurabh Jain do you mean textField.delegate=self in the Custom Cell VC?

Comment: table view delegate

Comment: @user1000 I am not sure what you mean. I also added a label into on of my prototype cell and that is not showing up either

Comment: @Saurabh Jain yes I set the delegate and dataSource to self in the viewDidLoad

Comment: You should set the textFiled text into your Custom Cell Class, Add a method  and call it.

Comment: @Saurabh Jain do I set textField.text = "Hello", in viewDidLoad for CustomCell?

Comment: Making delegate to be nil inside awakeFromNib method is not a good idea. You should set this in prepareForReuse instead. Also why do you need to bring the textfield to front? Is there any other outlets that are above that field?

Comment: @Kevin What count is returning in `numberOfRowsInSection`? It should return more than 0 or else you won't see the cell.

Comment: @Woof I have done a similar tableView and I had that code so I tried that thinking it would solve my issue. But no there aren't any other outlets above the field

Comment: @Kevin Add a method like func textForTextFiled(_ text:String) { textField.text = text } and call it like cell.textForTextFiled("Text") and all text filed delegate set in Custom cell class

Comment: Have you set the tableview delegate and tableview datasource in storyboard?

Comment: @Hooda was spot on. My dataSource was empty. Thanks for the check!

Comment: @Kevin, I have added it as an answer. Please mark it as accepted answer if you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data source is empty.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // data is not containing any value
    return data.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `data.count` it should have some data and also if that is custom cell with XIB then you need to register cell in view didload

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Your Cell XIB name", bundle: nil),
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your data.count. it must return value greater than 0 otherwise your tableView is showing with 0 rows and nothing is display in tableView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 // debug at this point check what is value of data.count its must be greater than 0
return data.count
}
```